# Rejecting an accepted PhD offer for another - Would really appreciate some advice/opinions!

Tags: phd, united-kingdom, academic-life, rejection

I just got some great news that I have been offered a full studentship on a PhD program that's currently my second most favourite option. I have only until March 16th to accept it or reject it. In the meantime, my most preferred option has not gotten back to me yet, even though I even emailed them explaining that I have a time-sensitive decision to make about another program, and that I would love to know what my chances of getting an interview invitation are. Even if they respond, I'm probably not going to know anything for sure before the 16th.

The potential supervisors at my second best option (and currently only certain one) are wonderful people - both of them got super excited that I got in, sent me the most supportive emails and well wishes, and are clearly looking forward to working with me. They also supported me quite a bit during the application process. I really like them, I really like the project too,but I would still want to hear back from this other option (which is at a more prestigious university).

I cannot get an extension on my current offer - the studentship is pretty competitive. If I reject it, they will be offering the PhD to someone on the waiting list. I can't help it but feel that the right thing to do is accept the offer now and then wait and see how the rest is going to play out - if I get the other (dream) PhD, I fear that I'd have to cancel my current offer later in the year and that the supervisors - albeit really nice people by the looks of it - might hold it against me. It will probably create some administrative hassle for them anyway..

If it does come to me being offered the other PhD (with funding), I don't really know how I'd have to approach my current supervisors. I know this is all hypothetical at this stage, but I can't help but overthink all possible scenarios anyway. I'd love to think that I will then just be able to be completely honest with them, explain my reasons and end on a respectful note. I don't want to ruin my relationship with them and I wouldn't want them to hold my decision against me. However, many people tell me that going back on an accepted offer looks really bad, that I will burn bridges, that it will be damaging for my future career in academia because I am likely to see and meet these people again, and that I should just accept my current offer and be happy that I got a fully funded PhD that >100 other applicants were apparently hoping to get. I haven't mentioned anything to the supervisors yet, as my other options are at best unclear, so it didn't really make sense to mention anything as yet. I was very motivated to get the PhD that I got too, and I think they see me as someone who is super motivated to start this particular PhD. While this is somewhat true, it's not entirely the case.

Has anyone been in a similar situation? How did you approach your supervisor/team, were you honest? If some of you have been in a similar position a while ago, do you feel you have suffered any negative consequences as a result? Any advice would be extremely helpful, also from people who have not necessarily been in that boat but would share their opinions and insights. :)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest checking our archives, there has been a lot of discussion about this over the years (including, but not limited to, the question linked above). But as you might expect, there is no "correct" answer; some people feel that turning down an accepted offer is unethical and should never be done, while others feel that applicants have to do what is best for them.

Comment: Just my personal opinion: you've been offered a highly competitive Ph.D. position that you clearly like and where you have good rapport with your potential supervisors. It is quite possible that if you accept it and later withdraw, this will be seen badly, and more importantly it is highly inconsiderate towards the other applicants. Are you sure that your preference of the other option is based on reasons which are tangible and certain enough to outweigh these considerations? The only reason you have mentioned is prestige of the university, which makes me doubtful that this is the case.

Comment: Among many friends doing PhDs in Oxford, UK, the running joke was they were paying fees so that they can do all the work themselves and be exploited by their supervisor. Some stories were horrific, like a friend who could only get any feedback from her supervisor if she did unpaid translations for him. Defo not claiming it's the norm, but certainly don't discount a supportive environment, and don't assume a "more prestigious" place would be as good.

Comment: As an aside, this sort of situation is why many US grad schools abide by the [April 15 Resolution.](https://cgsnet.org/resources/for-current-prospective-graduate-students/april-15-resolution/)

Comment: It has been my experience that it is uncommon to get a chance to do the work you want, with people you want to work with, and who want to work with you.  I regret the times I've turned my back on these chances, to chase money and prestige.

Comment: "_I can't help but overthink all possible scenarios anyway_" but all I can see in your question is the scenario where you accept option B and then option A tells you you've been accepted. What will you do if you reject option B and then get rejected or never hear back from option A?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Couple thoughts:

1. Ask for an extension to make your decision on the offer you have.
2. It is a mistake to assume that a prestigious institution will give you an advantage in any way simply by nature of being prestigious. This may be true for undergraduate work, but as a PhD student you will be judged on what you have produced during your PhD and truly, no one cares about the name of the institution. So if the other school gives you better access to resources that will advance your research or better funding, thats one thing, otherwise it doesn't really make a difference.

If you cannot get an extension, ask yourself what it is about your top choice (other than prestige) that makes it better than the option in front of you, and do your best to weigh whether that is really worth turning down this offer for. Understand that you may never get an offer from the other school.
Accepting an offer and then turning away is unprofessional and ill advised. Keep in mind that if you are in the sciences and these labs are both in the same subfield, the supervisors are potential future collaborators and it would be a mistake to spoil their impression of you at this stage with actions that would make you appear unreliable and unwilling to follow through with your commitments.

At the end of the day, remember: a bird in hand is worth two in the bush.

Comment: "... and truly, no one cares about the name of the institution". This is certainly how it should work, where we judge new PhDs on their work instead of the branding of their university. But unfortunately I've seen hiring committees form a first impression because a CV features a prestigious university. It's a shame. Still, this answer gives good advice.

Answer (score 19):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

I would think hard before trading this kind of support

> The potential supervisors at my second best option (and currently only
> certain one) are wonderful people - both of them got super excited
> that I got in, sent me the most supportive emails and well wishes, and
> are clearly looking forward to working with me. They also supported me
> quite a bit during the application process. I really like them, I
> really like the project too.

for the prestige at the other place.

Comment: Is that also based on your experience? I still have no way of knowing how supervision at the other place might look like, but the initial conditions seems pretty good too. I don't think I will be having bad supervision at my more preferred option, I simply don't have enought information yet and will hear back from them a lot later in the year.

Comment: Not my experience, just a response to the really good impression this place makes. To answer the question you asked: accepting now and reneging later is unprofessional behavior. Reneging "a lot later in the year" is particularly egregious since they can't then offer your place to someone else they also wanted when they chose you.

Answer (score -2):

Whatever you decide on March 16, I sincerely hope you think about how your decision impact your credibility. I do not recommend you negate your decision once you accepted the offer.

Comment: I disagree with this.  Institutions put pressure on student by deliberately having early deadlines.  If an institution makes a fuss about a student rescinding an accepted offer to choose a better offer elsewhere that comes in later, the student should not go there in the first place.

Comment: Can both of you expand? Why would that make me seem less credible, if I do explain that when I was accepting the offer it was the only one available? I'm planning to be honest if it comes to this, not to lie.